# ffmpeg won't stop encoding, even with -shortest command

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I am having an issue with ffmpeg stopping the encoding process, and searching on the internet has gotten me no working solutions. I am calling ffmpeg in Linux through Python's subprocess module, as so:

```
mergeFiles = subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg -i /home/pi/Video/video.mov -i /home/pi/Audio/test.wav -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest /home/pi/Final/output.mkv", shell=True)
```

The command prompt is waiting for me to manually end the encoding process with "ctrl-c", but I won't have access to a keyboard to kill the encoding. I just want it to stop when it's done. I have even attempted to use mergeFiles.kill() from Python after a couple seconds, and that doesn't even work. Help!

EDIT: If I wasn't clear, I meant that there is no error, ffmpeg simply won't continue until I hit "ctrl-c". I just want it to stop encoding when it's done. This is what my command prompt looks like:[image: ffmpeg error]

It's just waiting for me to press "ctrl-c"

Comment: You're using the old, counterfeit, fake "`ffmpeg`" from Libav.

Comment: Really? How do  I go about fixing that?

Comment: I don't know what version of Rasbian you're running (if that is what you're using), but you may be able to use `ffmpeg` from jessie-backports. Or perhaps try an armhf build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Next time please copy and paste all of the console text instead of making an incomplete image of the text.

Comment: I am running the Jessie version of Raspbian. I guess I didn't realize I was using a fake version of ffmpeg, as at one point I had things working just fine. And what I mean by that is I had ffmpeg merging my files just fine while completing the encoding process normally. Then all of a sudden ffmpeg wouldn't let me end encoding without hitting "ctrl-c". I realize that is vague, and I can't elaborate because I don't know why it all of a sudden stopped encoding properly. As for the console text, I simply ran the code I typed in and that was the response. I will get that armhf build now.

Comment: I have the same error for a live streaming, ffmpeg is still in "listen mode" to encode, but stream is closed and process remain in execution forever.

Answer (score -1):

When the file `/home/pi/Final/output.mkv` already exists, ffmpeg asks you to override the file and does nothing.

You can pass `'-y'` flag to overwrite.

Comment: I have my code to set up to delete anything in my "Final" folder before merging files, so it's not asking me to overwrite anything, it's just not automatically finishing the encoding. I have had the error of ffmpeg asking me to overwrite the file, but what's happening now isn't the same.

Comment: ... then debug 'what's happening' :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear in my original post. When I run the ffmpeg command, it's waiting for me to hit "ctrl-c" to end encoding, like [this](http://imgur.com/a/zc2KI). There's no "click a/y/n" type error.. it simply won't finish encoding.